# QStyledItemDelegate does not show desired Widget in the cells of QTableView

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, delegates, qwidget, qtableview

I want to test how to put `QSpinBox` into cells of `QTableView` in Qt 6.2.2, but the delegate does not appear to work, which means it does not show `QSpinBox` in the cells, and I've tested the delegate member functions by `qDebug` which reveals that none of these functions work! could anyone help to fix the problem? Many thanks in advance!

Below is the code:

testtabledelegate.h

```
#ifndef TESTTABLEDELEGATE_H
#define TESTTABLEDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>
#include <QWidget>

class TestTableDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TestTableDelegate(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

private:
};

#endif // TESTTABLEDELEGATE_H
```

testtabledelegate.cpp

```
#include "testtabledelegate.h"
#include <QSpinBox>

TestTableDelegate::TestTableDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{

}

QWidget *TestTableDelegate ::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    qDebug() << "Draw Control";
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(index);

    QSpinBox *editor = new QSpinBox(parent);
    editor->setFrame(false);
    editor->setMinimum(0);
    editor->setMaximum(10000);

    return editor;
}

void TestTableDelegate ::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    int value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toInt();

    QSpinBox *spinBox = static_cast<QSpinBox*>(editor);
    spinBox->setValue(value);
}

void TestTableDelegate ::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QSpinBox *spinBox = static_cast<QSpinBox*>(editor);
    spinBox->interpretText();
    int value = spinBox->value();

    model->setData(index, value, Qt::EditRole);
}

void TestTableDelegate ::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(index);
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

testtablemodel.h

```
#ifndef TESTTABLEMODEL_H
#define TESTTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractTableModel>

class TestTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TestTableModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

protected:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;

private:
    //QStringList *testList = QStringList() << "R1" << "R2" << "R3" << "R4" << "R5";
};

#endif // TESTTABLEMODEL_H
```

testtablemodel.cpp

```
#include "testtablemodel.h"

TestTableModel::TestTableModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{

}

int TestTableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 5;
}

int TestTableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 5;
}

QVariant TestTableModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
            return QStringLiteral("Field %1").arg(section);
        else if (orientation == Qt::Vertical)
            return section + 1;
        else
            return(QVariant());
    }
    else
        return(QVariant());
}

QVariant TestTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        return index.row();
    }
    else if (role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole)
    {
        return Qt::AlignCenter;
    }
    else
    {
        return QVariant();
    }
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
//#include "testtableheader.h"
#include "testtablemodel.h"
#include "testtabledelegate.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    TestTableModel *testModel = new TestTableModel();
    TestTableDelegate *testDelegate = new TestTableDelegate(this);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QTableView>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
    ui->tableView->setModel(testModel);
    ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(testDelegate);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: The editor widget is only shown why you try to edit the cell - did you do this?

Comment: I double clicked the cell but it still does not appear

Comment: What are the [edit triggers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop)?  Does `TestTableDelegate::createEditor ` get called when you double click on a cell?

Comment: Tried`ui->tableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked);`, still not working, and `createEditor` does not get called.

Comment: just because you set an edit trigger the editor will not show up - you also have to edit your cell by double clicking it.